# Image upload failing unexpectedly

Tags: php, upload

I have an image upload script that allows simple PHP upload of profile pictures. It is now unexpectedly failing on upload. I am not entirely sure why. I have checked the post_max_size and the upload_max_size and they are way over 1MB. I have a suspicion it is to do with the //Delete previous picture but not sure why. If you look at the query where it says;

```
AND image1 !='../files/noprofile.jpg'
```

This is so that if the profile picture is the default the image for the default is not deleted. I have a feeling it is to do with this part and the upload fails when the image IS the default profile picture.

I know i should be using mysqli but please don't mention that i am working on it.

Here's the entire script with a few thing taken out for simplicity purposes:

```
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$pass = $_SESSION['password']; 
$path = "../imageuploads/";

//Delete previous picture
$pic = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM members WHERE artist='Y' AND username='$username' AND password='$pass' AND image1 !='../files/noprofile.jpg'
")or die(mysql_error());

 while($fetchpic = mysql_fetch_array($pic)){ 

//if image1 does not equal no profile
unlink( $fetchpic['image1']); 

}


$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg1']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg1']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(2024*2024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg1']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                            mysql_query("UPDATE members SET image1='../imageuploads/$actual_image_name' WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$pass' AND artist='Y'");

                                echo "<p1><img src='../imageuploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='imageright1'></p1>";
                            }
                        else
                            echo "<p1>failed</p1>";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "<p1>Your image is a bit too big. It has to be below 1MB.</p1>";                   
                    }
                    else
                    echo "<p1>Only JPG, PNG GIF and BMP file formats are accepted.</p1>";   
            }

        else
            echo "<p1>You've gotta select an image first!</p1>";

        exit;
    }
```

Comment: list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", 'firstname.lastname.jpg'); will give an unexpected result

Comment: what do you recommend instead?

Comment: $explodedName = explode('.', $name); if(in_array($explodedName[count($explodedName) - 1], $valid_formats){ ....

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I did not think that would be the solution, it's just an extra safety for filenames with multiple dots. You did assign the right values to $txt and $ext when trying my example?

Comment: Oh okay. I had left your example in the script and yes I did. Having only been using PHP for a few weeks there are still large bits I dont understand so thankyou for the security measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form tag, add the attribute enctype:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```